# How to use nodejs ws module on secure site

Tags: node.js, https, websocket, ws

I'm using the following code to connect to WebSockets on a node js app for HTTP, but to doesn't work in HTTPS. What do I need to change? Is there a secure version of the node js ws module?

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

webSocketServer.on('connection', (webSocket) => {
    webSocket.on('message', (message) => {
        ...
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Pays to read the nodejs ws module documentation sometimes:

```
let webSocketServer;    
if (!local) {
    const server = https.createServer({
        cert: fs.readFileSync("/... server.crt"),
        key: fs.readFileSync("/... server.key")
        });
    webSocketServer= new WebSocket.Server({ server });
    server.listen(8080);        
    }
else webSocketServer = new WebSocket.Server({ port:8080 });
```

On the client-side, you need to call it with wss:// instead of ws://